# Exported Javafx application does not run as Jar file (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jar, manifest

I have a javafx application which is not properly exporting to a runnable jar file from eclipse. When exported the `.jar` file does not properly run and the GUI does not appear. Below is the Manifest File.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: gameaspects.SourceCodeVersion9
```

Here is the export interface:
[image]

Exporting the file produces no errors or warnings from eclipse.

Running the application from cmd I get the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at                 com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: .\music
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.find(Unknown Source)
    at gameaspects.SourceCodeVersion9.start(SourceCodeVersion9.java:81)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
```

Exception running application gameaspects.SourceCodeVersion9

The code that I believe that this is referring to is this:

```
List<String> result = Files.find(Paths.get(".\\music"), 100,
        (p, a) -> p.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3"))
        .map(path -> path.toString())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The .\music refers to the source folder `music` that is present in my application.

If any other information is needed to diagnose this issue please comment below and I will add it.

Comment: @fabian Edited question to provide the error.

Comment: Ok using the errors provided by the cmd I found and fixed the errors. However, I would like to know how to change the List<String> method to not name the same file twice.

Comment: BTW: Paths are relative by default anyways. There is no point in adding `.\\ `: `Paths.get("music")`. As for the file duplication: use [`Stream.distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) or if you have a existing list, use a `Set`, go through the list and remove all elements where `set.add(element)` returns `false`

Answer (score 1):

Ok using `java -jar FileName.jar` in command prompt and then using the stack trace to debug my code I was able to find the error with my application.